# Has hadoop fs -ls any option to return a subset of fields?

Tags: hadoop

The command

> hadoop fs -ls /data

Will return all subdirectories in the given path in the format:

> vdrwxr-xr-x+  - myuser mygroup 0 2017-02-13 14:23 /data/mysubdirectory

How could I make the command to return just some of the fields. For example date and subdirectory:

> 2017-02-13 /data/mysubdirectory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation shows no such option:

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#ls

You could pipe the output of **hadoop fs -ls** to something like awk and print the columns you want.

```
hadoop fs -ls /data | awk '{print $6 " " $8;}'
```

Here the example, done with AWK live editor:

https://awk.js.org/?gist=05aea37413e0e026af98689296705dbd

Another option would be to use the HDFS client API in Java or some other JVM language. There you can call [FileSystem#listStatus](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html#listStatus(org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path)) to get the [FileStatus](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html), which provides all the information **hadoop fs -ls** is printing to the console.

```
// Get configuration from HADOOP_CONF_DIR
// org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration configuration = ...

FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(configuration);

for (FileStatus fileStatus : fs.listStatus(new Path("/data"))) {
  // fileStatus.getModificationTime() -> format date
  // fileStatus.getPath() -> extract filename
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this may work. I followed another approach, but because I was using a sh.

Comment: np. going with "cut" is a good solution and it is easier than awk!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing like this:

```
hadoop fs -ls /data/ | while read f; do     
    echo ${f} | cut -d' ' -f 6,8
done
```

Where for this case 6 and 8 represents the fields Last modified Date and File Name. All possible fields returned by ls [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/07/linux-ls-command-examples/)